# I am unable to find locator using xpath for Selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Below is jscript code by Inspect Element

[image: Script]

It has many li and span tags. How do I write a Selenium command to click on IIS Menu?

When I tried with Firebug I got below code, can some one help me how to write Xpath for this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuDzc.png)

Comment: Would you edit into your question the code you are working on at present? What language are you using?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I found the correct way to find locators.Below is the code which works for me:

```
Actions action=new Actions(driver);
WebElement e= driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/div[3]/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/div/ul/li[7]/a/span")); 
action.moveToElement(e).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/form/div[3]/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/div/ul/li[7]"))).click().build().perform();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Xpath for the same, as there are same class name of all the `li` so better to used xpath. You can find it using Firebug and Firepath in Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: The question is what XPath can I use to locate these elements and your answer is use XPath. That's not really answering the question.

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried many options with Xpath, but unable to locate exactly.

Comment: Can you provide URL of the page